# $\infty + \infty = \infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, infinity

(The context is a measure-theoretic one.) I know that $\infty - \infty$ is indeterminate, but what about $\infty + \infty = \infty$?

It seems this statement is true and if I input it into Wolfram Alpha it says it's true. But [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122215/infinity-plus-infinity) it says it is not true and that this equation is also indeterminate. Is there some extra condition in the linked post that I am overlooking...surely $\infty + \infty = \infty$ always?

Comment: It really depends on what context you're in. Sometimes we have $\infty$ and $-\infty$ as separate objects, sometimes we just refer to either one by a single object called $\infty$. The correct answer depends entirely on what the context is.

Comment: Why is this tagged under set theory? If this is a set theoretical question, then there is no such thing as $\infty$. If this is not a set theoretical question, then what is it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I was dealing with measures on sets and this issue came up...I've removed the set theory tag.

Comment: Excuse me, but $\infty + \infty = \pi$. At least under my notation. But how are *you* defining the symbol $\infty$?

Comment: In a measure theoretic context, (positive) $\infty$ is treated as a formal object and in this setting, $\infty+\infty$ is a well-defined object and is defined to be $\infty$. Note that we can only add infinities as it is consistent with our underlying algebraic foundations. We cannot subtract infinities since this would cause some really awful paradoxes.

Comment: What if the first $\infty$ represents the number points in $[0, 1]$ and the second represents the number of positive integers, what does the statement mean?

Comment: @Avraham: But it doesn't. $2^{\aleph_0},\beth_1,\frak c$ and occasionally $\aleph$ represent the former; $\aleph_0$ represents the latter. Because set theory allows us to differentiate the two cardinalities, they are not denoted the same way.

Comment: I understand the cardinalities of the two are different; my point was that $\infty$ as a symbol is itself vague unless clearly specified.

Answer (score 4):

The linked post is about $\infty$ the point at infinity of the Riemann sphere/the complex projective line.

In that situation (like if $\infty$ denotes the point at infinity of the real projective line), $\infty + \infty$ is indeterminate, since $z_n$ and $w_n$ can approach $\infty$ in such a way that $z_n + w_n$ converges to any point of the projective line, or not at all. The addition cannot be continuously extended to $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\times \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ (resp. $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}\times \widehat{\mathbb{R}}$).

In the context of measure theory, $\infty$ is "positive infinity", which completes the non-negative half-line to $[0,\infty]$, and in that setting, the addition can be continuously extended to $[0,\infty]\times[0,\infty]$ by setting $x+\infty = \infty = \infty + x$ for all $x$, so there $\infty + \infty$ is not indeterminate.

It would still be better to use the symbol $+\infty$ to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

A good question might be *what does $+$ mean here?*

At a basic level, $\infty$ is not a number and can't be added like numbers. Without further clarification, this is how I treat infinities that I see for the first time.

In the real line, we might very well mean "arbitrarily large and positive" by $\infty$ (and "arbitrarily large [in absolute value] and negative" by $-\infty$). This is sort of how infinity gets played with in standard calculus courses. So here, $\infty + \infty$ is just another arbitrarily large and positive number, so we might say that $\infty + \infty = \infty$. On the other hand, $\infty + -\infty$ is indeterminate, because arbitrarily positive plus arbitrarily negative doesn't really mean anything.

Measures are typically functions $\mu:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}\cup\{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ and $-\infty$ might be interpreted as being "bigger than every positive number" and "smaller than every negative number", respectively. [There are more formal definitions of the extended reals, such as a two point compactification with the order topology]. Because of this, the standard operations on the reals can be partially extended to results of measures, and it isn't hard to show that having $\infty + \infty = \infty$ can be made both well-defined and meaningful here.

For contrast, some people might consider a complex measure $\nu: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ [aka the Riemann sphere, a 1 point compactification]. The complex numbers aren't ordered, which is why we don't care to add an additional symbol $-\infty$. In this case, we can't say that $\infty + \infty = \infty$ in any meaningful way, because now $\infty$ means colloquially "farther than any number from $0$."

So in short, with a standard measure, you can feel confident saying $\infty + \infty = \infty$ if you really want. But in many cases (and usually by default) people don't treat infinity like a number and thus don't try to add them together.